# AWS S3: NoSuchKey but key exists

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am using an AWS Lambda function where a user can specify a bucket key on an HTML page which corresponds to a CSV file in S3. The CSV file is read using boto3, tokenized, fed to a SageMaker endpoint, and a json string is returned by the Lambda function to the HTML page with AWS API Gateway. When I test all of this in AWS Lambda the JSON string returns fine, however, when I attempt to execute the Lambda function with the static webpage (hosted by S3) I get the following error messages in the browser console:

```
POST https://... 502 
favicon.ico:1 GET https://... 403
```

When I check the AWS CloudWatch logs for my Lambda function I see:

```
\[ERROR\] NoSuchKey: An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified key does not exist.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 54, in lambda_handler
    s3_response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET, Key=KEY)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 530, in \_api_call
    return self.\_make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 960, in \_make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
```

Which is confusing since I do not get this error when I test my lambda function using test events.

Here is my Lambda code:

```
import boto3
import json
import re
import pandas as pd # imported using AWS managed Lambda Layer AWSSDKPandas-Python310

REPLACE_NO_SPACE = re.compile("(.)|(;)|(:)|(!)|(')|(?)|(,)|(")|(()|())|(\[)|(\])")
REPLACE_WITH_SPACE = re.compile("(\<br\\s\*/\>\<br\\s\*/\>)|(-)|(/)")

def tokenize_words(comment):
words = REPLACE_NO_SPACE.sub("", comment.lower())
words = REPLACE_WITH_SPACE.sub(" ", words)
words = re.sub('\[^0-9a-zA-Z\]+', " ", words)
words = words.split()
words = " ".join(words)
return words

def output_df(output, scraped_df):
output_dict = {'Irrelevant': \[\],
'SomewhatRelevant': \[\],
'Relevant': \[\]}

for i in range(len(output)):
    d = output[i]
    p = d['prob']
    output_dict['Irrelevant'].append(round(p[0], 2))
    output_dict['SomewhatRelevant'].append(round(p[1], 2))
    output_dict['Relevant'].append(round(p[2], 2))
    
prob_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(output_dict)
pred_df = pd.concat([scraped_df, prob_df], axis=1)
sorted_df = pred_df.sort_values(by = ['Irrelevant', 'SomewhatRelevant', 'Relevant'], 
                                ascending=True, 
                                ignore_index=True)
return sorted_df

def lambda_handler(event, context):
# S3 URI: s3://scraped-comments/2022/Cybersecurity.csv
CSV_FILE = str(event['body'])
BUCKET = 'scraped-comments'
KEY = f"2022/{CSV_FILE}.csv"

runtime = boto3.Session().client('sagemaker-runtime')

# S3 data
s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
s3_response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET, Key=KEY)
df = pd.read_csv(s3_response.get("Body"))
tokenized_comments = [tokenize_words(x) for x in df.Comment.values.tolist()]
num_comments = len(tokenized_comments)

payload = {"instances" : tokenized_comments, "configuration": {"k": num_comments}}

# Now we use the SageMaker runtime to invoke our endpoint, sending the text we were given
response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName = endpoint_name,
                                  ContentType = 'application/json',
                                  Body = json.dumps(payload))

output = json.loads(response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8'))
bt_df = output_df(output, df)

json_string = bt_df.to_json(orient='records')
return {
    'statusCode' : 200,
    'headers' : { 'Content-Type' : 'text/plain', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*' },
    'body' : json_string
}
```

Additionally, I am a novice at coding in HTML and JavaScript so perhaps the problem lies in my HTML page which is here:
`

```
    Ranking Engine
    
    


    <script>

    function submitForm(oFormElement) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var jsonData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
     
xhr.onload = function() {

    let container = $("#container");
     

    let table = $("<table>");
     

    let cols = Object.keys(jsonData[0]);
     

    let thead = $("<thead>");
    let tr = $("<tr>");

    $.each(cols, function(i, item){
        let th = $("<th>");
        th.text(item); 
        tr.append(th); 
     });
     thead.append(tr); // Append the header row to the header
     table.append(tr) // Append the header to the table
     
     // Loop through the JSON data and create table rows
     $.each(jsonData, function(i, item){
     let tr = $("<tr>");
        
        // Get the values of the current object in the JSON data
        let vals = Object.values(item);
        
        // Loop through the values and create table cells
        $.each(vals, (i, elem) => {
           let td = $("<td>");
           td.text(elem); // Set the value as the text of the table cell
           tr.append(td); // Append the table cell to the table row
        });
        table.append(tr); // Append the table row to the table
     });
     container.append(table) // Append the table to the container element
  }
  xhr.open (oFormElement.method, oFormElement.action, true);
  var key = document.getElementById('key');
  xhr.send(key.value);
  return false;
 }
</script>

</head>
<body>

    <div>
        <h1>Text Classification Engine</h1>
        <p>Type a bucket key to see comments classifed as one of the following topics:</p>
        <div style="float: left; width: 50%;">
        <ul>
          <li>Relevant</li>
          <li>Irrelevant</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div style="float: right; width: 50%;">
        <ul>
          <li>Somewhat Relevant</li>
        </ul>
        </div>

        <form method="POST"
              action="https://..."
              onsubmit="return submitForm(this);" > 
            <div>
                <label for="key">Enter a key here (example provided):</label>
                <textarea  rows="5" id="key">Cybersecurity</textarea>
            </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <div id="container"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

`

It may also be of note that my lambda function usually takes ~40 seconds to complete execution so perhaps there is a timeout issue, but I am unsure.

The API Gateway for feeding data to the SageMaker endpoint is a REST API with POST method execution, Integration Request Type Lambda, Method Request Auth: NONE, Method Response HTTP Status: 200, and Models: application/json => Empty.

The API Gateway for communication between my Lambda function and the front-end webapp is a REST API with ANY method execution, Method Request Auth: NONE, Integration Request Type Lambda Proxy, Method Response HTTP Status: Proxy, and Models: application/json => Empty.

I suspect this might be due to a permission error. My Lambda function has the AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole, AmazonS3FullAccess, and AmazonSageMakerFullAccess roles. The S3 bucket that holds the CSV data has Block All Public Access enabled with the following bucket policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowS3Access",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/LAMBDA_ROLE"
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::scraped-comments",
            "arn:aws:s3:::scraped-comments/*"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I also do not have a CORS policy set if that is of any relevance.

Comment: FYI that bucket policy does not enable Block (All) Public Access. Public access is denied by default but that specific policy statement is not the reason why.

Comment: If you got a NoSuchKey response then your request definitely made it to S3 and there is definitely no object with that key in the associated S3 bucket. Debug log your bucket name and the object key then go and check them. Ensure that the key does not begin with forward slash (a common error). If you aren't able to find an obvious cause then please update your post to include the object key so we can see it.

Comment: I'm by no means an AWS expert. In the Permissions tab of the bucket I see "Block All Public Access" with a green checkmark. In an attempt to have Lambda access the bucket, I added the bucket policy afterwards.

Comment: You should give the Lambda the permissions it needs in the IAM policy associated with the IAM role that the Lambda function is configured to run with. That's a better way to do this than in the S3 bucket policy. Both approaches work but the former is preferred.

Comment: It's not clear from the code you've posted, but how are you sure that the value generated by `KEY = f"{event\['body'\]}.csv"` leads to a proper key?  Have you output that variable when running as a Lambda to verify it contains what you think it does?  What are you passing to the endpoint in the first place?

Comment: I've edited my post to include how I determined the bucket and key names. The S3 URI is  s3://scraped-comments/2022/Cybersecurity.csv so I believe the bucket name should be `scraped-comments` and the key name should be `2022/Cybersecurity.csv`. My Lambda function has AmazonS3FullAccess which leads me to believe it should have access to the bucket with the CSV data.

Comment: Are you sure that the `event[body]` your lambda is getting is just the string "Cybersecurity" and nothing more? That seems unlikely to me.

Comment: What does `CSV_FILE` contain when your Lambda is invoked?  You've not shown how you're calling the Lambda, or what the events contain when you do call the Lambda.  Without that information, we can only guess what's going on.

Comment: Using the webapp, I am trying to send "Cybersecurity" in the `event` variable so when I access `event['body']` I can receive it. The way I am attempting to send "Cybersecurity" is `var key = document.getElementById('key'); xhr.send(key.value);` from the textarea tag in my HTML. If I am sending something more than just "Cybersecurity" from my webpage, I am unaware how to correct the issue.

Comment: It's straighforward to review what the client sends and what the Lambda function receives. You should actually check both rather than assume what the values are.

Comment: My apologies, but I am a novice in both AWS and HTML. If you could be more explicit in how I can check what the client sends and what the Lambda function receives I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: Add something like `print(f"CSV_FILE is '{CSV_FILE}')` after you set CSV_FILE, and then check the output in CloudWatch logs.

Comment: CloudWatch has notified me the output value for CSV_FILE is 'None'. Now I suspect the fault is in my HTML/JavaScript code. How can I ensure I am sending the correct string to my Lambda function?

Comment: You can use the [network panel](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/) of your browser to see what data is being sent to API Gateway.

Comment: I discovered that the reason why 'None' is being sent to my server is because `var jsonData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);` needs to be within the scope of my `xhr.onload = function()`. After small change, I was able to retrieve data from my S3 bucket. Thank you@AnonCoward for suggesting I print `CSV_FILE` and check the CloudWatch logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the reason why 'None' is being sent to my server is because var jsonData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); needs to be within the scope of my xhr.onload = function(). After small change, I was able to retrieve data from my S3 bucket. Thank you@AnonCoward for suggesting I print CSV_FILE and check the CloudWatch logs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).